# A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.[ios, xcode]

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have android and ios app in react native which both uses webview to show webpage as application.
Since I had to change package name to deploy it on google play since first one package name was occupied. I changed app.json file and all names in android folder and that's ok.

Now my question is what I need to change in my ios folder in order to my app work in xcode. I have this error.

> Invariant Violation: "RestApp" has not
> been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

This is my app.json file

```
{
  "name": "restapphhopp",
  "displayName": "RestApphhopp"
}
```

Index.js file

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: are u solve it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The issue here is with the **name** you are using for your app

```
Invariant Violation: "RestApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:

    Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
    A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called.
```

your index file is using the **appName** from app.json **name** field to register your component, which in your case is **"name": "restapphhopp"**

change your **moduleName** in ios AppDelegate.m file to **restapphhopp**

```
moduleName:@"restapphhopp"
```

Comment: What about expo?

Comment: there is no moduleName in AppDelegate.m, react -native 69.2

Comment: same with me, there is no moduleName in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: if you still have issues with android, in your MainApplication.java file in the method getJSMainModuleName return your new name.

Answer (score 13):

Name in the app.json should be the same as the name in package.json

Comment: In order to complete this answer (For my case, was the correct answer), in iOS environment you have to have the same name in:
- app.json
- package.json
And in the module name in the AppDelegate file

Answer (score 5):

recheck your name is same in app.json and in strings.jsx file

Answer (score 3):

I also needed to edit this line in `AppDelegate.mm`

`UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"YOURAPPNAME", nil);`

After updating this, in addition to all other steps, I then ran

`npm start --reset-cache`

Open new terminal:

```
cd ios
pod install
npm run ios
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

if using expo

1. delete node_modules and your lockfile (package-lock.json / yarn.lock)
2. run yarn or `npm install`
3. run `expo install react-native-safe-area-context`

Comment: Does it work for actual react native apps too or it is only for expo? I mean should i write expo install react-native-safe-area-contex for react native app?

Answer (score 1):

Check the App name in MainActivity at *getMainComponentName* function, app.json, and package.json. Try to keep the same in these 3 places.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after many uses I found the issue was on the  "drawer"
you may find the issue in another package if you are not using the drawer.
In my case :

I upgraded the package react-navigation/drawer to 6.6.3

"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3" in  package.json,

Comment: You are right. I am also faced the same issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I used a boilerplate for react-native and I had to change the name 'template' for 'theNameOfMyCurrentProject' with npx react-native-rename "the Name Of My Current Project" . After that I had to replace manually in AppDelegate.mm 'template' for 'theNameOfMyCurrentProject' . And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue and solved by cleaning gradle

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native run-android
```

Hope this will also work for you

Answer (score 0):

Fix for expo app that worked for me...

Add Reanimated's babel plugin to your babel.config.js as below:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
    ]
  };
};
```

Then make sure to import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; it at the very top of your App.js or index.js file as below:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when installing "react-native-circular-progress-indicator" , try

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade
react-native-gesture-handler to v2.14.0
and react-native-reanimated to v3.6.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "nameApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I got same err

Answer (score -4):

1. First, you will need to start Metro, the JavaScript bundler that ships with React Native. Metro "takes in an entry file and various options, and returns a single JavaScript file that includes all your code and its dependencies."

```
npx react-native start
```

2. Let Metro Bundler run in its own terminal. Open a new terminal inside your React Native project folder. Run the following:

```
npx react-native run-android
```