# expo start: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered with no other errors

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

I'm trying to use `npx expo start` with my "pure" react-native project (i.e. I created the project using React Native's CLI)

When I run `npx expo start`, I get this error:

```
iOS Bundling complete 36518ms
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

Following this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64167281/a-module-failed-to-load-due-to-an-error-and-appregistry-registercomponent-wasn), I made sure my app name is 'sotravelapp' in `package.json`, `AppDelegate.mm` and `index.js`, which imports the name from `app.json`. Which is weird that the error message says 'main' instead of 'sotravelapp'.

So I tried changing the names in those three files to 'main', and *that* made it work.

So it seems the name is stuck as 'main'. Which seems to be what [this expo documentation is saying](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/). How do I change it to the name I want?